# CNAME and redirects

Tags: cname-record, openshift-online-2

Many thanks for the free service on OpenShift.

I am using Gandi for my domain - `www.something.io` (₁), `something.io` (₂). I am trying to achieve the following: Have domains ₁ and ₂, redirect to `nodejs-something.rhcloud.com` without having the rhcloud domain in the address bar. I am aware of masked forward but wouldn't that display the rhcloud domain name? Why is forwarding the naked name so problematic?

---

The below works fine for `www.something.io` only:

```
something.io 3600 IN CNAME nodejs-something.rhcloud.com.
www 3600 IN CNAME nodejs-something.rhcloud.com.
www.something.io 3600 IN CNAME nodejs-something.rhcloud.com.
```

`something.io` displays:

```
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at nodejs-something.rhcloud.com Port 80
```

after I setup forwarding in Gandi from `*.something.io` to `www.something.io`. It wouldn't even take me to `something.io` if I didn't, that is, it ignored my rule in the zone file above.

I really wish this was a bit more simple.

I am very new to this so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: CNAME RRs cannot co-exists with other RRs, such as NS or SOA.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use CNAME record for the root of the domain. You'll need to use an A record instead, but an A record can only point to an IP address, so you'll need to find the IP address of nodejs-something.rhcloud.com.

Does this rhcloud server allow you to configure host headers on the web server? If so, you'll also need to have an entry on your webserver to recognise something.io and display the appropriate web content.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was hoping to get an OpenShift-specific answer. 

I don't think they have IP addresses for the server.

Comment: If you can get access to some basic web hosting, you could point your root domain to that, and then have that webserver perform a redirect to www.something.io